Write an if-statement which tests against all elements in an namespace
I have a namespace, which contains many elements. Using an if-statement, I want to evaluate if my variable int test = 0 is equal to any element within my namespace.
As example:
namespace A {
   int FOO = 1;
   int BAR = 2;
}

int test = 0;
// Evaluating against all elements of the namespace
if (test == A::FOO || test == A::BAR) {
    //...
}

However, if my namespace has many elements, testing against all of them by stating them individually is not feasible. What would be a good way to do that?

"testing against all of them by stating them individually is not feasible" yes it is, all of them had to be declared one by one to begin with.

Store your values in a collection of some kind.

why is FOO and BAR not elements of a container? You are using a namespace not how it is supposed to be used. And what you want to do can be done differently

Do you want enum (class) instead of namespace?

C++ doesn't have reflection yet, and you would need to filter compatible element.

Looks like you should read about data driven tests. You didn't provide information which test library you are using so can't provide a demo.

You could use an X macro.  (I hate macros.  Macros are The Devil™.  I wouldn't do it this way.  But the capability is there.)

this is an xy problem. If you'd tell us why you want to compare all variables inside a namespace in an if condition perhaps we can tell you how you can achieve the same (but possibly in a different way)

You could also create a set inside your namespace and add the value of each of variables into it:
std::set<int> s = {FOO, BAR /*add here further variables if you want*/};

and then you can check whether A::s.contains(test).

depending on what OP actually wants, the set could contain pointers to reflect modifications of A::FOO and  A::BAR

@463035818_is_not_an_ai yes, indeed. My answer focuses on providing a simple solution for the specified problem. Surely, if there are unmentioned further needs, then the OP may specify the question further which would compel modifications on this answer.

If types of parameters are the same, may be easier to create a vector (to iterate by indexing) or map (to iterate by names) and iterate over it?
